# Css sticky position event

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm using CSS `position:sticky;` to stick a div to bottom of the page.

Is that possible to change the width (or something else) of the div **when the element is sticked**?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed make use of event listeners to invoke css when your target hits the bottom of the page. You can find useful information on this guide:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sticky-headers

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible to apply **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** to an element with **[`position: sticky`](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)**.

Here's an example showcasing that:

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cae8ca;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
```

Note that [**support**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) for `position: sticky` is spotty, however. It is not supported in some of the semi-recent versions of Edge, Firefox and Chrome, along with not being supported in Internet Explorer at all.

Also note that even in a valid browser, `position: sticky` will not work when the parent element has either `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Wrong answer! This is not really answer to this question. Please read the question again. => **when** the element is sticked

Comment: @Pedram -- Can you please explain how this is the 'wrong answer'? As far as I am aware, this not only answers the question, but also lists the caveats. It was even upvoted, so others agree with this answer. Re-reading the question, I still believe it is the 'answer'. Considering the grammar was broken in the original question, I don't personally think semantics over the *timing* of **when** the element becomes sticky. I personally believe the OP was simply asking whether sticky elements could have a `width` (regardless of *when* they become sticky).

Comment: Maybe up voted because they misunderstood the question as you or just blindly up vote due your rep. Yes I know, if I want, can make answer, no words, but still thinking about what OP want. You made an answer, so I prefer to explain for you, then you can get *some easy points*. `Is that possible to change the width (or something else) of the div when the element is sticked?` OP want to change `width` when `element` sticked. You just say about possibility of add `width` to an `element` with sticky property. But OP want to change `width` after that.

Answer (score 0):

I've made one more solution for this problem. It uses same idea as [Eric Bidelman's](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sticky-headers) but can cover some more corner cases.

You need to create some additional elements to track sticky header position. Eric calls them sentinel. In my solution they are thin `1px` lines.

1. Add one sentinel for each sticky side you want to observe.
   Set first sentinel top property equals to header top but with reverse sign minus
2. For example if your header have top: `10px`, then set sentinel header to `-11px`. You can use something like top: `calc(-1px + -1 * var( — header-sticky-top))` or just set `-1px` if you have header top equals to zero.
3. Add other sentinels if needed.
4. Observe sentinels intersection with container using Intersection observer.
5. You can say that header stuck if sentinel intersection record has `isIntersecting = true`, `intersectionRatio = 0`, and `intersectionRect.top = rootBounds.top`.
6. Same other sides, just watch bottom, left, or right instead of top.
7. Don’t forget to add `visibility: hidden` and `pointer-events: none` to sentinels.

You can find demo and source in this article: 
https://medium.com/@yavanosta/another-event-for-css-position-sticky-445a8d5663a

Comment: Thank you for reply. Added some key facts from the article directly to SO post.